# JQuery Ajax loading external html with loader

Tags: jquery, colorbox, uploading

Is it possible to have [colorbox](http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/core/example2/index.html) and its animations in an expanding div rather than a new modal window? Not sure colorbox is the correct way to do this.

I want to ajax load external html into a div but keep the close, animation and loading functions colorbox has.

Any thoughts would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Certainly! colorbox simply looks at the `href` attrbibute of the `<a>` tag that you're applying colorbox to. It doesn't matter whether that tag links to an image or an html file, it will load the content into a fancy colorbox frame.

For example, in your main page content:

```
<a id="colorboxMe" href="yourPage.html">Click to see yourPage</a>
```

And in your javascript:

```
$('#colorboxMe').colorbox();
```

Clicking the link should load the contents of `yourPage.html` into an expanding div.

EDIT: Oh, I didn't understand your question. I guess if you don't want the overlay and the centered frame, you could change it with some css. Add this to the CSS of your main page:

```
#cboxOverlay {
    display: none;
}
#colorbox {
    position: relative;
    display: inline;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
}
```

EDIT EDIT: This probably won't work because the script will override these css declaration. I don't know what the solution is.

Comment: Ok, that's great I can upload yourPage.html so easily. But does colorbox have to use this modal window/frame. Can I have the same look (animation and loader) in a regular div on my myIndex.html.

Comment: oops, i misunderstood your question. You could hack it together by messing with the CSS as I've demonstrated above.

Comment: Actually, since the script will just override this css when it creates the element, it probably won't work. Sorry, I don't think I have an answer for you.